# Tag rename request: [rockstargames-social-club] -> [rockstar-games-social-club]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-rename-request

The official name of the service is Rockstar Games Social Club, as you can see from Rockstar themselves:

[image]

Wikipedia:

[image]

And the excerpt of the tag:

> Rockstar Games Social Club is a stat tracking, digital rights management, multiplayer and communications service provided by Rockstar Games for use with many of their titles (e.g. Red Dead Redemption, Grand Theft Auto IV, LA Noire, Max Payne 3).

The change is simple [rockstargames-social-club](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rockstargames-social-club) is renamed to [rockstar-games-social-club](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rockstar-games-social-club).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems reasonable enough. Done.